# Get Top Most Parent From XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

How do I get the top most parent element from XML? I need the entire element with its attributes.

It wont always be the first line as there might be comments.

```
string xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\GRPAdmin\Desktop\Test.xml");

XElement str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
var h1 = str.Parent;
var h2 = str.XPathSelectElements("..").FirstOrDefault();
var h3 = str.XPathSelectElement("..").Parent;
```

```xml
<FILE NAME="ABC" version="14.0.0.112" State="WIP" Template="ABC123" origin="designer">
 <REC NAME="Recipient">
    <FLD NAME="FirstName">James</FLD>  
  </REC>
 <REC NAME="Message">
    <FLD NAME="Key">123</FLD> 
  </REC>
 <REC NAME="Details">
    <FLD NAME="Key">default</FLD>    
  </REC>
</File>
```

I would expect to have a var that equals `<FILE NAME="ABC" version="14.0.0.112" State="WIP" Template="ABC123" origin="designer">` as the desired result

Comment: In your code `str` already reference 'the top most parent' aka the root element, if I understand the question correctly. Post the expected output if it isn't the root element that you want actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XML data model, the opening tag (including all the attributes), tag content, and the closing tag is single XML element object, so it isn't natural to request only the opening tag. I'm not aware of a bult-in .NET function to get that, but you can reconstruct the opening tag string by combining information of the tag name, and all the attribute name-value pairs, for example :

```
string xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\GRPAdmin\Desktop\Test.xml");

XElement str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
var attributes = String.Join(" ", str.Attributes().Select(o => String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", o.Name, o.Value)));
var result = string.Format("<{0} {1}>", str.Name, attributes);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jeNCzp)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<FILE NAME="ABC" version="14.0.0.112" State="WIP" Template="ABC123" origin="designer">
```

Comment: The built-in .NET method to walk the XML tree tag for tag, attribute for attribute etc is to use `XmlReader`. But I doubt it is required here, it's a low-level API that you better stay away from unless you know what you are doing and your need requires it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`XElement.AncestorsAndSelf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346865%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to walk up the chain of parent XML elements to the root element.  [`Enumerable.Last`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) then gives you the root element:

```
var root = element.AncestorsAndSelf().Last();
```

If the `XElement` is contained by some `XDocument`, you can always do

```
var root = element.Document.Root;
```

But in your case you parsed directly to an `XElement` without bothering to create an `XDocument` container.

Answer (score 0):

as @har07 already said, str is the top most element. If you want the attributes just iterate over them

```
string xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\GRPAdmin\Desktop\Test.xml");

var root = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
foreach (var attribute in root.Attributes())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", attribute .Name, attribute.Value);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `attribute.Name` and `attribute.Value` in the loop body?